# Conditional Json Expression and for loop in jsr223 post processor in jmeter

Tags: for-loop, groovy, jmeter

unable to use variables in groovy in conditional jsonpath expressions, was able to pass jmeter variables, but varibles created in the script are not working.. In the below code if i pass value or jmeter variable at ${"dat"+n} it is working fine but in case if i pass "dat" variable which is generated in post processor it is throwing error..

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList myList1 = new ArrayList();
for( int i = 1; i<= ${relationshipID_matchNr};i++){
myList.add (Integer.parseInt(vars.get("relationshipID_"+i)));
}
log.info(""+myList);
for( int n = 1; n<= ${relationshipID_matchNr}-1;n++){
String s = myList[n].toString();
vars.put("dat"+n,s);    
myList1.add 
(com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..[? 
(@.identifier == ${"dat"+n})]..columns.[?(@.type == 
"relationship")].token'));
}
```

Comment: I even tried vars.getObject and vars.putObject both of them are failing..

Comment: Please show the error, or reason of failure

Comment: 2019-07-24 17:32:43,551 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Expected character: )
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:162) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with $ character you have to use escape character **'\'** is required for $.
Please use **'\$'**

Comment: Its not working and i am able to pass ${dat} value in that condition, if i try to loop this value by appending some value to it, i am getting an error@H P @Dmitri T

Comment: @NarendraSai Can you show me what is JSON body? Also What is exception you are getting after changing JSON path to (com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '\$..[? 
(@.identifier == \${"dat"+n})]..columns.[?(@.type == 
"relationship")].token'));